# Server not reachable after "service networking restart"

Tags: networking, crash

I just had a problem with my iptables, so I tried to use:

`service networking restart`

I lost the connection to all of my VM's (running a proxmox server). So I rebooted the master server, where I executed the command.

Now it only pings, but I can't connect to it. Nmap says that all ports are closed. 
There is a rescue mode available, so I can still access all of my data.

How can I fix it? Or - as I read it somewhere else - is it a big problem and I won't really be able to fix it?